# Inconsistent line height between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm working on custom tooltips for my site, and I'd like them to look the same on Chrome and Firefox. Everything works as expected, except that each line of the tooltip seems to have a different height on Firefox, despite my definition of `line-height` and adding `!important`.

I have some JS set up to set the text of and move the tooltip to the cursor's position, but I doubt that's what's causing the line-height issue.

Here's the CSS:

```css
#tooltip {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: <?= $theme['fgTooltip'] ?>;
    line-height: 120% !important;
    background: <?= $theme['bgTooltip'] ?>;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    user-select: none;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

And the generated HTML:

```html
<div id="tooltip" style="display: block; opacity: 1; left: 265px; top: 644px;">
    <b>Test.md</b>
    <br>Last modified: 9/26/2021 2:09 AM
    <br>File type: Markdown Document
    <br>File size: 146 Bytes
</div>
```

[The result in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj2VT.png)

[The result in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBtz0.png)

Any ideas why this is happening? Is it just a weird thing with Firefox?

All responses appreciated!

**Edit:**
After looking at the rendered result in Firefox's DevTools, I discovered that each line of text is 19px tall, but the line breaks are 19.6px tall. That also explains why the last line of my example tooltips (and single-line tooltips) don't have this problem. How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: My tests are giving me the same line height so maybe I'm putting in linefeeds in a different way to you. Could you show us the HTML for that tooltip?

Comment: @AHaworth I've added the HTML to my question. I'm writing another edit now since I found something that makes this even more strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, for some reason, `<br>` elements in Firefox don't want to properly respect the line-height of their parent.

I fixed the issue by setting the `line-height` of all `<br>` elements to `0%`.